# Nunit unit testing of .Net core Web API 5.0

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, asp.net-core-webapi

Is there any proper good resource to learn unit testing of .Net core Web API with EF Core/Dapper as ORM & having N-tier architecture using NUnit ?? I am not finding any proper resource on controller testing, service layer testing, Data access layer testing, middleware testing etc

Answer (score 0):

The book 'Practical Test-Driven Development using C# 7' by John Callaway and Clayton Hunt covers most of these topics. The examples use MSTest, but can easily be transfered to NUnit.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I am new in unit testing, so are the syntax & coding style of MsTest same as NUnit?

Comment: The following articles list the differences beween the two test frameworks:
http://automationtipsntricks.blogspot.com/2017/10/mstest-vs-nunit.html

https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/nunit-vs-xunit-vs-mstest/